# Eclipse/Subversive deep outgoing state

Tags: eclipse, subversive

In Eclipse you can enable/disable "Compute deep outgoing state for folders" in Window | Preferences | Team | SVN | Label Decorations (or in other versions apparently -> Window | Preferences | Team | SVN | Performance).

The [Documentation](https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_performance.php) provides very little information about the functionality of this. ("Specifies if the computing of deep outgoing state is enabled.")

I was wondering what exactly does it do? What is a deep outgoing state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a dirty (changed but not committed) file is prefixed with `>`. Folders that contains the dirty file are also prefixed with `>`. Here is an example where only the file `Project/path/to/file.txt` is dirty:

[image]

Without *Compute deep outgoing state for folders* the same example looks like this:

[image]

To compute the `>` dirty label for folders, the subtree of the folder have to be checked/visited for dirty files. **By disabling *Compute deep outgoing state for folders* no subtrees need to be checked/visited**, but **dirty files are harder to find**, especially when an ancestor folder is collapsed.

Comment: How are the dirty files found when the subtrees are not visited? (In your second example e.g. - how is file.txt determined to be dirty if it stops at Project)

Comment: SVN has for each file the check-out version of the file, the so called _base from working copy_. A file is dirty if the working copy differs from its base version. To compute the dirty flag the file must be compared with its base version. In the second example, only dirty flags of visible files are calculated and displayed (cost: one file comparison per visible file), whereas in the first example, the dirty flags of all (whether visible or not) files of the project must be calculate which can be very costly.